Inequality between nth prime and a certain integer sequence
I've noticed the following while playing around with primes:
Define a sequence as:
$$a_1 = 2$$
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + \left \lfloor{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{a_k-1}}\right \rfloor$$
Define the $n$th prime as $p_n$.
It appears then that $p_n \leqslant a_n$.
I've checked this for all primes below $10^6$ using python, after which it becomes increasingly difficult due to the fast growth of the nominator/denominator of the fraction.
Is it true?

@JohnOmielan Isn't it $p_k \leqslant a_k$? I don't understand how the last inequality is derived.

I'm sorry, that was a mistake. As such, I've deleted my previous comment.

These are called Problimes, see the sequence A003066. It has links to some articles, maybe some of them helps.
